# How to lazy load Tags in CQ dialog

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

If a page has a lot of Tags assigned, loading the dialog can take quite some time (up to 20 seconds). If the author only wants to change some other property on multiple pages this can get rather annoying. The question is thus, is there a way to lazy load Tags in a dialog?

To be more precise I am talking about the "classic UI" based on ExtJS.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two ways to achieve this, both using a button to trigger the load:

**Open a sub dialog:**

```
<button
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    text="Open Tags Dialog"
    handler="function(button) {
        var parent = button.findParentByType('dialog');
        var dialog = CQ.WCM.getDialog(PATH_TO_DIALOG + '.infinity.json');
        dialog.setFormUrl(parent.form.url);
        dialog.loadContent(parent.form.url);
        dialog.show();
    }"
    xtype="button"/>
```

Explanation: the handler gets triggered on click. It loads the sub dialog, sets the submit url and the source from where the data should be loaded to the same node as the current dialog.

**Overwrite tab** (button resides in its own tab):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
    title="Tags"
    extensionGet=".json"
    xtype="customcontentpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <button
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            text="Load Tags"
            handler="function(button) {
                    var parent = button.findParentByType('panel');
                    var tabConf = CQ.shared.HTTP.eval(PATH_TO_TAB + '.infinity.json');
                    var tab = CQ.Util.formatData(tabConf);
                    for (var i=0; i&lt;tab.items.length; i++) {
                        parent.add(tab.items[i]);
                    }
                    parent.doLayout();
                    parent.loadContent();
                    parent.remove(button);
                }"
            xtype="button"/>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Explanation: The `cq:Panel` needs to use the `xtype="customcontentpanel"` and the `extensionGet=".json"`. The other properties are by default inherited from the dialog that contains this panel.
`CQ.shared.HTTP.eval` loads a JSON and transforms it into a JavaScript object.
`CQ.Util.formatData` then translates the XML attributes like `jcr:primaryType` to `xtype`.
Then just iterate over all elements the just loaded tab configuration and add them to the current tab. As these widgets were added after the initial load of the dialog `doLayout()` needs to be called again as well as `loadContent()`. The last step is to remove the button.

Comment: What a ridiculous helpful solution: basically this way we could use `cqincludes` via JavaScript for optimal code reuse. Thanks a lot.